# Jupyter will not launch from Anaconda Navigator 32bit

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I read where running installing pyqt5 or pip install pyqt5 would correct this error.  Did not work for my enviornment.  Any suggestions?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
import sqlite3
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in 
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?  You wrote *I read where running installing pyqt5 or pip install pyqt5 would correct this error* so it seems you tried something that did not work.  We're more likely to be able to help if you can share that.

Comment: Yes,  This is the response posted:

Comment: I tried updating and installing it through anaconda prompt (comes preinstalled with your anaconda installation) at first, by typing:
conda update pyqt5 later (when it said it wasn't found):
conda install pyqt5
but, sadly it couldn't locate any library named pyqt5 in their repository.
Instead: pip install pyqt5.

Comment: I launched jupyter from Anaconda Navigator and received this:     Traceback 
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 10, in 
import sqlite3 File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Traceback 
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in from notebook.notebookapp import main File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 86, in 
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
File "C:\Users\Paula\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 13, in 
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'